# Converting VC++ .LIB files to .DEF files

Tags: c, opengl, static-libraries, glew, tcc

I was having problems with compiling OpenGL applications, and I found out I was using the wrong GLEW library. But I can not find the GLEW static library in the .def format. Does anyone know how I could make a definition file or were I can find one?

Comment: What compiler you're using?

Comment: the tiny c compiler, but i'm pretty sure the .def format is the same as borland's format. thank you for responding!